# Cleaner way to check for a datatable in a dataset and then remove/add datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

What I have is functioning 100%, however I'm wondering if there is a cleaner, more effcient, or higher readability way to do this, or if checking one by one is the way to go.

```vb
If XMLDataSet.Tables.Contains(CabinetTable.TableName) Then
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Remove(CabinetTable.TableName)
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(CabinetTable)
Else
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(CabinetTable)
End If
If XMLDataSet.Tables.Contains(DocTypeTable.TableName) Then
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Remove(DocTypeTable.TableName)
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(DocTypeTable)
Else
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(DocTypeTable)
End If
If XMLDataSet.Tables.Contains(IndexTable.TableName) Then
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Remove(IndexTable.TableName)
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(IndexTable)
Else
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(IndexTable)
End If
If XMLDataSet.Tables.Contains(CabinetToTypeTable.TableName) Then
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Remove(CabinetToTypeTable.TableName)
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(CabinetToTypeTable)
Else
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(CabinetToTypeTable)
End If
If XMLDataSet.Tables.Contains(TypeToIndexTable.TableName) Then
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Remove(TypeToIndexTable.TableName)       
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(TypeToIndexTable)
Else        
    XMLDataSet.Tables.Add(TypeToIndexTable)
End If
```

---

I presume I could make a sub to do this, something like:

```
Private Sub addRemoveDataTable(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal dt As DataTable)
    If ds.Tables.Contains(dt.TableName) Then
        ds.Tables.Remove(dt.TableName)
    End If     
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
End Sub
```

But I'd still have to call that for every DataTable so I don't see it being any more efficient.

---

### EDIT:

I completely forgot about using a paramarray for the data tables...

```
Private Sub addRemoveDataTable(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal ParamArray dTable() As DataTable)
    For Each dt As DataTable In dTable
        If ds.Tables.Contains(dt.TableName) Then
            ds.Tables.Remove(dt.TableName)
        End If
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Next
End Sub
```

However each iteration of the For loop is just having called one of the sets in the first option, So I still can't see much improvement in efficiency. but this option is easier to read and quite a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you feel about extension methods, you could add an extension method to `DataSet`.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ExtensionMethods

    <Extension> Public Sub Replace(ByVal dataSet As DataSet, ByVal dataTable As DataTable)
        If dataSet.Tables.Contains(dataTable.TableName) Then
            dataSet.Tables.Remove(dataTable.TableName)
        End If
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)
    End Sub

End Module
```

And then your code would become:

```
XMLDataSet.Replace(CabinetTable)
XMLDataSet.Replace(DocTypeTable)
XMLDataSet.Replace(IndexTable)
'...
```

Comment: I've never implemented an extension method before. What keeps that extension from being called on something other than a dataset? As in what keeps me from doing `not_a_dataset.replace(datatable)`? I'm guessing the first parameter is the parent object and since it's restricted to a dataset in it's declaration, that's how it knows?

Comment: @BrandonB: Yes, by the first parameter.

Comment: @pmcoltrane   I like how clean this is. When I get chance, if I can, I'm going to put in a paramarray so I can pass it multiple tables and only call the method once.

Is there any reason why I wouldn't be able to use a param array as the second parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Less code? (Call your method using a For Each loop)

```
For Each t in XMLDataSet.Tables
    addRemoveDataTable(XMLDataSet,t)  
Next
```

...

```
Private addRemoveDataTableSub(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal dt As DataTable)
   If ds.Tables.Contains(dt.TableName) Then
      ds.Tables.Remove(dt.TableName)
   End If     
   ds.Tables.Add(dt)
End Sub
```

Comment: As you were posting that I edited my post. I added the for loop using a paramarray... Like I said I still don't see it being more efficient, it still has to execute the same amount or more lines in the end, regardless of them being consecutive or in a loop.

Comment: @BrandonB I don't think efficiency would be a problem, it's just an if statement, calling a method, etc. Don't worry about it.